# CASE clause inside WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, case

can anyone tell me why I can not run this code in SQL Management studio?
Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT  * FROM TabKontaktJednani
where
TabKontaktJednani.Typ IN (
CASE 'ERP'--(SELECT ALIAS FROM TabCisZam where LoginId = SUSER_NAME())
WHEN 'ERP'
THEN ('HeO','OST')
WHEN 'TO'
THEN ('SW','OST')
END)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't run that code is that `CASE` expressions can only return one scalar value, not a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` expression returns a tuple. That is not allowed in SQL. But as MySQL supports a boolean data type, a `CASE` expression may result in a boolean:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabkontaktjednani
WHERE 
  CASE (SELECT alias FROM tabciszam WHERE loginid = suser_name())
    WHEN 'ERP' THEN typ IN ('HeO', 'OST')
    WHEN 'TO' THEN typ IN ('SW', 'OST')
  END;
```